# JNA - How to use typedef Callback

Tags: java, c++, jna

i am using JNA to use an DLL.

and i had a doubt.

in my former code i had in library.h:

```
NET_DVR_API LONG __stdcall NET_DVR_function_V30(LONG lUserID, LPNET_DVR_CLIENTINFO lpClientInfo, void(CALLBACK *fRealDataCallBack_V30) (LONG lRealHandle, DWORD dwDataType, BYTE *pBuffer, DWORD dwBufSize, void* pUser) = NULL, void* pUser = NULL, BOOL bBlocked = FALSE);
```

In java using JNA I define the following:

```
public interface NewFrameCallback extends StdCallCallback {
    void invoke(int lRealHandle, int dwDataType, Pointer pBuffer, int dwBufSize, int pUser);
}

int NET_DVR_function_V30(int lUserID, HCNetSDKLibrary.NET_DVR_CLIENTINFO lpClientInfo, HCNetSDKLibrary.NewFrameCallback fakeFuncPointer, Pointer pUser, boolean bBlocked);
```

and it worked.

Now i receive an new dll, and i need to use other function:

in .h is defined:

```
typedef void (CALLBACK *REALDATACALLBACK) (LONG lPlayHandle, DWORD dwDataType, BYTE *pBuffer, DWORD dwBufSize, void* pUser);

NET_DVR_API LONG __stdcall NET_DVR_function_V30(LONG lUserID, LPNET_DVR_CLIENTINFO lpClientInfo, void(CALLBACK *fRealDataCallBack_V30) (LONG lRealHandle, DWORD dwDataType, BYTE *pBuffer, DWORD dwBufSize, void* pUser) = NULL, void* pUser = NULL, BOOL bBlocked = FALSE);
NET_DVR_API LONG __stdcall NET_DVR_function_V40(LONG lUserID, LPNET_DVR_CLIENTINFO lpPreviewInfo, REALDATACALLBACK fRealDataCallBack_V30 = NULL, void* pUser = NULL)
```

in java i only add:

```
public interface NewFrameCallback extends StdCallCallback {
    void invoke(int lRealHandle, int dwDataType, Pointer pBuffer, int dwBufSize, int pUser);
}

int NET_DVR_function_V30(int lUserID, HCNetSDKLibrary.NET_DVR_CLIENTINFO lpClientInfo, HCNetSDKLibrary.NewFrameCallback fakeFuncPointer, Pointer pUser, boolean bBlocked);
int NET_DVR_function_V40(int lUserID, HCNetSDKLibrary.NET_DVR_CLIENTINFO lpClientInfo, HCNetSDKLibrary.NewFrameCallback fakeFuncPointer, Pointer pUser);
```

obviously its not working how to i use the typedef in JNA? Looking for the new .h the REALDATACALLBACK looks identical to the CALLBACK *fRealDataCallBack_V30!

Comment: `int pUser` should be `Pointer pUser`, though this will only make a difference on 64-bit platforms.

Comment: Your V40 mapping needs to drop the last `boolean` parameter.  That's probably what's trashing your stdcall stack.